# How to render JSP in such a way that in dropdown of that field the checkbox(not exactly checkbox it is created by using id) will be selected

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc, model

**Here I have a configuration model**

```
private int[] jobExecDaysInWeek;
//here setters and getters
```

**jsp**

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label-bg col-xs-12">Daily <span class="red">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 f-size-16">
          <form:select path="jobExecDaysInWeek" id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple">
            <form:option value="0" label="Select"></form:option>
            <form:option value="1" label="Sunday"></form:option>
            <form:option value="2" label="Monday"></form:option>
            <form:option value="3" label="Tuesday" ></form:option>
            <form:option value="4" label="Wednesday"></form:option>
            <form:option value="5" label="Thursday"></form:option>
            <form:option value="6" label="Friday"></form:option>
            <form:option value="7" label="Saturday"></form:option>
          </form:select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

while creating new record the same jsp structure i am using i am getting the correct result, but while editing i am not getting desired result.

Please find the expected result with the checkbox selected for the values present in the path, for e.g. in this 'jobExecDaysInWeek' i have 1,2 and 3
the respected checkboxes should be selected and presented like in the image below with checked fileds.

As we can see in dropdown it is checkbox but i am not creating checkbox i am using id to for that display.

[image]

but i am getting results like.

[image]

Comment: show us your code. Small snippet will not help us.

Answer (score 1):

In editing code you have to place code as you given above for selection, and bind value from database to checkbox list.

Comment: exactly. my question is when i am giving the path variable as array type it is not showing as a dropdown list, it is showing like pic 2, how to show like above jsp.
The above code is for editing jsp still not getting the results.